# How to create load test for SSE using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, server-sent-events

I am testing rest service which has subscription end point with header(2 key value pairs) values. On sucessful subscription I get 200 ok and soon get data streaming. How can I load test this in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

As of [current JMeter version 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) there is no built-in SSE support.

The options are in:

1. Consider another load testing tool which supports SSE like [Gatling](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/sse/)
2. Add SSE support to JMeter by adding a library which supports server sent events like [okhttp-eventsource](https://github.com/launchdarkly/okhttp-eventsource) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and implement your test scenario using [JSR223 Sampler(s)](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language. Check out [How to Load Test SSE Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-sse-services-with-jmeter/) article for more information if you decide to stay with JMeter