# How to load test an SSE Endpoint in 2023?

Tags: load-testing, server-sent-events

I want to write a load test for my SSE endpoint which is written with Quarkus & JAX-RS. Because I want to make sure that my server can withstand at least 100 or more open SSE connections. I ask this question because the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286692/how-to-create-load-test-for-sse-using-jmeter) was some time ago. So what is the best way to achieve that in 2023?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Gatling](https://gatling.io/) tool [has SSE support](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/sse/) now
2. You can also consider using [sse-perf](https://github.com/matthiasn/sse-perf) project, see [Load Testing Server Sent Event Streams](http://matthiasnehlsen.com/blog/2013/05/11/load-testing-server-sent-event-streams/)
3. It's still possible to use [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) however you will need to write custom Groovy scripts like it's described in [How to Load Test SSE Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-sse) article